# Change tab page icon in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

is this possible to change the tab page icon as if loading the page when I call function $.ajax() and on success or error again change icon to default? I need this because when the slow internet connection the user can see that something is loading and it will be wait for ending of process. In addition, I don't need the popup with the loading icon.

Comment: So, I know how to change page icon dynamically, I didn't find how to change it to animate icon or force the browser to display loading icon when ajax function in process.

Comment: Hey Sanprof I had the same issue a while back and just happened to release my code yesterday on github: https://github.com/nicolasbize/faviconx

Answer (score 0):

You could try with jQuery or other DOM manipulating library (or even with plain JS) to change/add/remove favicon.
It should be put in `<head>` section

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

And make sure that your favicon is animated gif.